# Python: defining new variables by calling a local variable of the same name

Tags: python

I've created a method that assigns a value to a local variable based on certain conditions. I'd like to then transfer that value into a variable outside the function in order to use it elsewhere. This is for a text adventure I'm working on.

```
    class Player(object):
        def __init__(self, player_name):
            self.player_name = player_name
        def JobType(self):
            print("Please select your job:")
            print(" ")
            print("1. name1")
            print("2. name2")
            print("3. name3")
            print("4. name4")
            global jobChoice
            jobChoice = input()
            jobs = ["name1", "name2", "name3", "name4"]
            if jobChoice == 1:
                jobChoice = jobs[0]
            elif jobChoice == 2:
                jobChoice = jobs[1]
            elif jobChoice == 3:
                jobChoice = jobs[2]
            elif jobChoice == 4:
                jobChoice = jobs[3]
            else:
                print "Invalid job"
            print("You are now a " + jobChoice)
            return jobChoice
        def JobStats(self):
            playerHP = 0
            playerAttack = 0
            playerDefense = 0
            playerLuck = 0
            if jobChoice == "name1":
                playerHP = random.randint(70, 85)
                playerAttack = random.randint(6, 9)
                playerDefense = random.randint(6, 11)
                playerLuck = random.randint(14, 17)
            elif jobChoice == "name2":
                playerHP = random.randint(70, 85)
                playerAttack = random.randint(7, 10)
                playerDefense = random.randint(6, 11)
                playerLuck = random.randint(3, 6)
            elif jobChoice == "name3":
                playerHP = random.randint(120, 200)
                playerAttack = random.randint(200, 600)
                playerDefense = random.randint(6, 11)
                playerLuck = random.randint(200, 600)
            elif jobChoice == "name4":
                playerHP = random.randint(70, 85)
                playerAttack = random.randint(8, 11)
                playerDefense = random.randint(6, 11)
                playerLuck = random.randint(7, 10)
            return(playerHP, playerAttack, playerDefense, playerLuck)
```

Addmittedly, *jobChoice* is a *global*. I don't want that, but that's also a part of my problem with extracting the value of local variables to be used in other functions.

So if I wanted a new *playerLuck* variable to have the same value as my local *playerLuck* variable inside the method, *jobStats*, how would I go about getting that value? :

```
    playerLuck = ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Extracting the value of local variables" should be done in one of two ways; either:

1. Explicitly `return` that variable; or
2. Make it a class or instance attribute, so it can be accessed `Class.attribute` or `instance.attribute`.

As you already have a class, you could easily have instance attributes `self.jobChoice` and `self.playerLuck`. Then you can easily access them:

```
player = Player(...)
...
if player.jobChoice ...:
```

Comment: How would I refer to these attributes outside of the class?
playerLuck = player.playerLuck ?

Comment: You refer to them as `self.attr` inside the class, and `instancename.attr` outside.

Comment: I'm sure it does; welcome to the world of *actual* object-oriented programming!